# Referencing from folder to folder

Tags: php

I am not sure I am doing this right.

I have a file at

```
/var/www/paymill-payment-form-master/request.php
```

In this file I need to reference to 3 other files that are in a different directory:

```
/var/www/paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill
```

So what I am doing is this:

```
require "/paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Transactions.php";
require "/paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Clients.php";
require "/paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Payments.php";
```

I am not sure the the code is wrong because of a reference error or something else.

Comment: You need to start with a `./` or `../` if you want to use the relative path otherwise it will fail as it will take it as a absolute path. The single dot is when its on the same directory and the double dot for previous folder.

Comment: Hey, everybody, what abour an *absolute path*? Should not there also be a possibility to address the files this way?!? If the web-root is at `/var/www/` then `/paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Transactions.php` should be pointing to the right location, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading slash is probably your issue. Starting a search path with `/` means to start from the top of the file system tree.

Consider using relative paths:

`require "../paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Clients.php"`

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions are the same but you were the faster by 17 sec :)

Answer (score 3):

do like

```
require "../paymill-php-master/lib/Services/Paymill/Transactions.php";
```